# Odoo14 tag tree can customize 2 rows of headers?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

As the title says, I want to know if the tag tree can be rendered. Can you have this kind of information?

If yes, please show me how to write the code. thank you very much

[image: 1]

This is my sample code.

```
<page name="test_header" string="test header">
    <tree string="My Tree">
        <field name="field1"/>
        <field name="field2"/>
    </tree>
</page>
```

Comment: I don't think this kind of feature is available in Odoo.

Comment: thank you very much I thought it could be done.

Comment: It could be done with custom code

Comment: If I want to custom code like this, how do I fix it? And where can I study?